# html exclude text from clipboard copy

Tags: html, css, clipboard

I have a span inside another span. I would like to allow the user to be able to select the text from the parent span, but not the child one.

Note: `user-select` (family) does not work. It prevent the selection to start or end in this area, but the text is still in the end clipboard result if I surround it with the select in the text from the parent span.

For example:

```
<head>
<style>
  .hole-hint {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 45%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:rgb(255, 0, 0);
    background-color:rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.5);
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .hole {
    padding-top: 7px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <span> this is the parent text<span class="hole"><span class="hole-hint">no copy</span></span>and this is text on the other side   </span>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What do you have now for markup?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need, I used place holders for text that wasn't entered yet. However if the user wanted to copy that block of text they would never want the place holders in the copied text. I came up with the following solution.

Here is an example, it uses some jquery but that could be replaced

CSS (not really needed just for fun)

```css
div.copying { background-color: yellow; }
div.copying .nocopy { display: none; }
```

HTML (Note: if you wanted to apply to the entire page, move oncopy to )

```html
<body>
  <div>text not related to the copy, dont select this</div>
  <div oncopy="handleHideCopy(this);" class="container">
    <span>the text between &gt;<span class="nocopy"> I don't want this text copied </span><span>&lt; will be excluded from copy, or at least in IE</span>
  </div>
  <div>and don't select this either</div>
</body>
```

JS

```
function handleHideCopy(el) 
{
    $(el).addClass('copying');
    var innerHtml = el.innerHTML;
    $(el).find('.nocopy').remove();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(el).removeClass('copying');
        $(el).children().remove();
        el.innerHTML = innerHtml;
    },300);
}
```

The reason why this works is because oncopy is called on the parent element before the copy takes place, and the content that must be hidden has to actually be removed, as display:none does absolutely nothing for copy.

Instead of using innerHTML for large amounts of html a more targeted DOM remove/insert should be used to remove the content and put it back where it belongs. I don't have an example handy for that.

Comment: Nice trick. Have used this at https://github.com/ahgittin/brooklyn-docs/blob/68291a398f4205b79af8021744db9ca0d081e46a/_layouts/base.html#L70-L97 with a slight tweak, just `hide()` then `show()` the `.nocopy` bits.

Comment: .hide() has the effect of doing 'display:none', did you test this cross browser before you continue?